# VBA - Conditional Formatting Formula Condition includes $ (invalid character)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Whenever I use the formula in the second row of the code (i.e. "=ISBLANK("$K2")) I receive the message "invalid character". If I use "=ISBLANK(""$K2"")" instead there is no error, however, the formula in my conditional formatting console includes the "" and thus it is not working properly/as expected.

````
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ISBLANK("$K2")"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False ```
````

Comment: `"=ISBLANK($K2)"`? Cell references shouldn't be surrounded by quotes.